# PostgreSQL: Changing multiple PK/id, while keeping its relation in other table

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 table, `Pricelist` & `Items`, each items record have a ForeignKey to `Pricelist` Primary Key.

See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e3a74844058956b1f3d5ef0c6830c8ce

**Question:**
is there a way to bulk change the `pricelist_id(pk)`  for example `pricelist_id` (`1` & `2`) to (`10` & `11`) (**autoincrement**), while keeping its relation in `Item table` on other words, the value `pricelist_id` in `Item` table adjusted to the new `Pricelist` id.

Pricelist table:

[image]

Item table:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A primary key should never be changed, that's why it's the primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to avoid conflict when importing record from old data source, i need to do database copy from old data source, while current table already have some records inside, let say 10 record, pk = 1-10. before moving record from other data source (sqldump) which have 20 record, (1-20), i think i need to change the current data to 21-30 before importing data with pk 1-20 .